# Checking a check box by entering its id

Tags: jquery, checkbox

Is there a way to check an unchecked check box by just getting its ID?

I have many jquery checkboxes and I just want to know if its possible that by just inputing its ID in a textbox, it will go through all my checkbox using each and, compare the inputed text and its ID... Then checked it if it is found.

Let's just say that what i have in my html is a textbox, a number of checkboxes and button.

```
<div id = 'fCheck'> 
  <input type="checkbox" id="mango" value="mango" /> <label>MANGO</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="santol" value="santol" /> <label>SANTOL</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="guava" value="guava" /> <label>GUAVA</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="lomboy" value="lomboy" /> <label>LOMBOY</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="apple" value="apple" /> <label>APPLE</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="orange" value="orange" /> <label>ORANGE</label><br>
</div>
```

Any idea on how to do this? A demo will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div id = 'fCheck'> 
  <input type="checkbox" id="mango" value="mango" /> <label>MANGO</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="santol" value="santol" /> <label>SANTOL</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="guava" value="guava" /> <label>GUAVA</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="lomboy" value="lomboy" /> <label>LOMBOY</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="apple" value="apple" /> <label>APPLE</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="orange" value="orange" /> <label>ORANGE</label><br>
</div>

<input id="checkTxt" type="textbox" />
<input id="checkBtn" type="button" value="check 'em" />
```

```
$("#checkBtn").click(function(){
  $("#" + $("#checkTxt").val())[0].checked = true;
})
```

for those sticks in the mud who don't want to use .prop I guess >.>

Comment: this is good but i just dont know why It wont run in my own program... But thank you for this. I just have to check my code why it won't check my checkbox

Answer (score 1):

Essentially you need this snippet to check the checkbox.

```
$('#apple').prop('checked', true);
```

jQuery 1.6+ only though. To also get it from the text area do something like this:

```
$('.inputclass').keyup(function() {
    $('#' + $(this).val()).prop('checked', true);
});
```

Here's it in action, you will want to tweak it to your needs: http://jsfiddle.net/nwYj5/1/

Comment: Am I correct in saying that they made `.attr()` backwards compatible for 1.6.2?

Comment: @Seth yes it should do the same thing

Comment: this is good, but since I am not using jquery 1.6+, then it will still not work for me. This may help somebody else.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 $("input:checkbox").each(function(){
         $(this).attr("checked", $(this).attr("id") == $("textBoxSelector").val()?true:false);
    });
```

Comment: this code is good but it removes the check of a check box once you input another id. Thanks for this sample

Comment: Yes, it will because the condition will fail and it will set checked property to false. What do you need exactly?

Comment: I already have it now. `$("input:checkbox").each(function(){if $(this).attr("id") ==  rightGroupCode){ $(this).attr("checked",true);}});`. I combine all the code that I have tested here and there I got it.

Comment: You mean rightGroupCode contains all the codes? Is it an array or a string?

Answer (score 0):

Given    `<input type=text id='checkMe' value=''>` you can define an event handler

```
$('#checkMe').live("keyup", function(){
   var id = this.value;
   $("#"+ id).attr("checked",true);
});
```

Note if you are using jquery 1.6+ you can use prop instead of attr.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4bxsu/11/) is your example

I added a textbox so you could have user input for the id:

```
<div id = 'fCheck'> 
  <input type="checkbox" id="mango" value="mango" /> <label>MANGO</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="santol" value="santol" /> <label>SANTOL</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="guava" value="guava" /> <label>GUAVA</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="lomboy" value="lomboy" /> <label>LOMBOY</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="apple" value="apple" /> <label>APPLE</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="orange" value="orange" /> <label>ORANGE</label><br>
</div>

<input type="text" id="userInput"/>
```

And here is the jquery (1.6)

```
$(function() {
    $("#userInput").keyup(function(e) {   
        if(e.keyCode === 13) {
            var checkbox = $("#" + $(this).val());
            checkbox.prop('checked', !checkbox.is(":checked"));
        }
    });      
});
```

If you want to use jQuery 1.5 you need to change checkbox.prop with checkbox.attr('checked', 'checked')